# Serverless Framework: Output compiled CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, serverless

I am using the serverless framework for a lambda project. We need to be able to access the cloudformation directly to meet with our standards for other projects. How can I view the full CloudFormation that is compiled from `serverless.yml`?

Comment: Haven't worked with serverless framework before, but does it not run a cloudformation script as usual in the Cloudformation console?

Comment: @WarrenG It does run through CloudFormation in AWS, I just need to capture the output locally and save it to a file on the project. There is a `serverless print` method, but it only prints out the filled in serverless template with real values

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Running the `package` command will generate 2 compiled Cloudformation templates in your service directory, one for stack creation and another for the stack update:

```sh
sls package
```

They'll be available in the folder `.serverless` as `cloudformation-template-create-stack.json` and `cloudformation-template-update-stack.json`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I found a plugin that will output a SAM Template from serverless which solved this problem. Here is the link: https://github.com/sapessi/serverless-sam